# Flux architecture one complex store versus two smaller

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux

What is better solution, make more smaller stores or less bigger. ? For example i have settings, and there are two pages - `graphSettings`, and `productSettings`
Have i write for them one or two stores? what is more effective solution.. 
For exemple my local data in first store looks - http://pastebin.com/GYEJ9fhT .. its a lot of rows, and its just for graphSettings... with productSettings it will be even larger.. So have use one or two ?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if `graphSettings` and `productSettings` are completely exclusive then it would make sense to have two different stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good practice to separate where you can, it'll benefit you in the future. The smaller and simpler your components/files are, the easier they'll be to develop, test and debug.